# Pandas read_sql not fetching all records from MS sql database

Tags: sql, sql-server, pandas, jupyter-notebook, pyodbc

I am trying to fetch data from MS sql server using Pandas on Jupyter.I have established a connection using pyodbc. However, I am unable to get all the rows from the tables. It doesn't give any error too. Example below:

```
xref = pd.read_sql_query(""" Select * from abc """, cnxn)
```

This query fetches 25,736 rows. However, that table has 48,475 records in the table and I am able to fetch all of them using Alteryx. I have failed to understand whats going wrong here. There doesn't seem to be any pattern for the rows it is not fetching.

Comment: could you perform a `select count(*) from abc` and `print xref.shape` for us to verify that please?

Comment: Yes it gives the same results - 25736 rows.

Comment: @Parfait, that was a typo. Its MS Sql server and I am using the same server and connection parameters to connect at both places

Comment: Then there is only 25,736 and NOT 48,475. Carefully check where this latter number derives. Be sure it is same exact `SELECT` statement. And use MS tools (SSMS or sqlcmd) to verify row count.

Comment: I have the same issue and my `pandas + sqlalchemy` only return 292 rows, when there should be >2000.